# What hashing algorithm is fast and good enough for checking if source data is changed?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Not sure if this falls into crypto from contextual point of view but it is about hashing algorithms. I have two directories -- assets/ and cache/. Anytime there is a file added, deleted, or changed in the `assets/` directory, a corresponding, application specific file will be generated in the `cache/` directory. On top of that, an additional "cache file" gets created that stores the following information:

```
assetFile: my-file.png # relative to assets directory
cacheFile: my-file.ktx2 # relative to cache directory
assetHash: 709a0aef5d1ecda90fb3f3542aa71bef08b9fab8 # hash from contents of asset file
cacheHash: 0511420356589c5669c83daeff059d68078aef80 # hash from contents of cache file
```

These files are generally huge. Some of these files can be 15-20mb in size.

The general purpose is not about security or privacy but it is more about checking if the source data is changed. So, in the example above, if `my-file.png` is changed, the application will check the file's contents against the hash stored in the "cache file" and if the hashes do not match, it will recreate `my-file.ktx2` and update the "cache file" with a new hash. The assets are generally added by the user themselves; so, if they try to willfully tamper with this system, they will be breaking their own workflow.

What kind of hashing algorithm can I use here that is fast enough to create the hash but also reliable enough in terms of not having false negatives (i.e collisions)?

I am currently using Sha256 hash and it is quiet slow, especially on large files.

Comment: Are you sure you're bottlenecked by hashing the file, and not by reading it from disk?

Comment: You don't have to worry about collisions when using any modern hash function with a 256-bit output. For large files, accelerated BLAKE3 is probably the fastest you can get. However, there's an issue with some BLAKE3 implementations that causes bugs with large large files (e.g. 2 GiB). Also, SHA-2 with acceleration is [fast too](https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3/issues/207).

Comment: "user **them**selves; ... **tamper** with this system". Upon reading this part, randomized hashing using a static secret key came into my mind (think HMAC).

Comment: @CodesInChaos This is something that also came into mind but I have not done profiling on this yet; however, I have around 80kb of file for testing and it was quiet slow. I also wanted to know if SHA2 is an overkill for my situation.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 What do you mean by acceleration in this case? Do CPUs have specialized instructions to make hashing faster?

Comment: @Gasim Yes, there are different instruction sets that provide hardware acceleration, improving performance. In the grand scheme of things, these are not large file sizes. You should investigate the performance of how you're reading from disk and the SHA-2 implementation you're using. I have a program for hashing with various algorithms, and hashing a 35 MiB file with SHA-256 is practically instant.

Comment: As long as you stream or memory map it. It's amazing how many file hash & encryption routines on e.g. [so] simply read things in memory first (and if you are unlucky, perform some interesting and unnecessary encoding actions on top of that, it seems like a minimum of 3 in memory copies is the minimum for some reason or other).

Comment: I don't know what you mean when you say "quite slow", but even without specialized instructions SHA-256 should be able to hash several hundred megabytes per second per core. If you're much slower than that, you're either IO bound, or you're using an inefficient implementation.